# Designing an audit trail for billing purposes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, data-modeling, audit, audit-logging

We're working on Rails apps with a pricing model similar to that of Amazon DynamoDB (i.e., flexibly provision what you'll need). For the sake of simplicity, let's say you can configure:

1. Number of users
2. Number of documents you're allowed to create

## Requirements

Simply put, you pay based on what you configure. Our specific requirements are as follows:

1. You pay a monthly fee based on the maximum for the month. If you upgrade to 1,000 users on the 3rd and downgrade to 500 on the 10th, you pay for 1,000 users for the whole month.
2. You can upgrade anytime.
3. You can downgrade once a day.

(This may sound unfair at first glance, but we're allocating some serious resources here.)

I am looking for a way to design a datamodel that does what we want without getting in the way too much.

## Things I've considered

### Auditing gems

As far I can see, I cannot use gems like [simple_audit](https://github.com/gtarnovan/simple_audit) or [paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail).

They store model changes serialized in the database. This is great for undo and versioning, but not for requirement #1 because **you cannot get the changes within a date range and then find the MAX value** (without calculating most of it in Ruby).

### Home-made solution

I can imagine the following home-made solution: A database table that stores records like

```
(model, metric, value, time_of_change, user_who_made_the_change)
```

This makes it possible to:

- have all changes in a single place
- query the maximum within a date range (requirement #1)
- query when the next change is allowed (requirement #3)

This table would be updated in an ActiveRecord (presumable `after_save`) callback which is [wrapped in the transaction around `save`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save).

I have concerns about the home-made solution because of [NIH Syndrome](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NotInventedHere), and maybe my concerns about the auditing gems are completely unsubstantiated.

Or, just maybe, I am overlooking an aspect or a whole other solution. What do you think?

Comment: The home-made solution looks good to me. `paper_trail` is good, I use it a lot, but you need reports/stats not an audit trail. You proberbly  don't need `time_of_change` just use `created_at`.